# Linux Stack Sizes

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I'm looking for a good description of stacks within the linux kernel, but I'm finding it surprisingly difficult to find anything useful.

I know that stacks are limited to 4k for most systems, and 8k for others.  I'm assuming that each kernel thread / bottom half has its own stack.  I've also heard that if an interrupt goes off, it uses the current thread's stack, but I can't find any documentation on any of this.  What I'm looking for is how the stacks are allocated, if there's any good debugging routines for them (I'm suspecting a stack overflow for a particular problem, and I'd like to know if its possible to compile the kernel to police stack sizes, etc).

Comment: what kernel version are you working with? so we have a better idea of the kernel debug configuration options available to you.

Comment: I don't seem to get this. Why isn't a debugger sufficient for the task ?

Comment: "bottom-halves" probably share the same stack. Also, "bottom-halves" disappeared a long time ago, now there are softirqs left.

Comment: Use the `ulimit -s` command. The result is in KiB.

Comment: Is this about userland or kthreads? Userland: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/145557/how-does-stack-allocation-work-in-linux/239323#239323

Answer (score 41):

The reason that documentation is scarce is that it's an area that's quite architecture-dependent.  The code is really the best documentation - for example, the `THREAD_SIZE` macro defines the (architecture-dependent) per-thread kernel stack size.

The stacks are allocated in [`alloc_thread_stack_node()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.2/source/kernel/fork.c#L204).  The stack pointer in the `struct task_struct` is updated in [`dup_task_struct()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.2/source/kernel/fork.c#L872), which is called as part of cloning a thread.

The kernel does check for kernel stack overflows, by [placing a canary value `STACK_END_MAGIC` at the end of the stack](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.2/source/kernel/fork.c#L835).  In the page fault handler, if a fault in kernel space occurs this canary is checked - see for example [the x86 fault handler](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.2/source/arch/x86/mm/fault.c#L833) which prints the message `Thread overran stack, or stack corrupted` after the Oops message if the stack canary has been clobbered.

Of course this won't trigger on *all* stack overruns, only the ones that clobber the stack canary.  However, you should always be able to tell from the Oops output if you've suffered a stack overrun - that's the case if the stack pointer is below `task->stack`.

Answer (score 6):

You can determine the process stack size with the `ulimit` command. I get 8192 KiB on my system:

```
$ ulimit -s
8192
```

Comment: Low quality answer, because question was about kernel. Quote _"stacks within the linux kernel"_.

Comment: @MilesRout My bad, I think it concerned the kernel stack size.

Comment: Indeed seems that this is not the correct place to answer that, but sincerly help me with looking for process stack size (as the question answers it)

Comment: @ManoelVilela type `ulimit -s` into the cmd line

Answer (score 1):

For processes, you can control the stack size of processes via `ulimit` command (`-s` option). For threads, the default stack size varies a lot, but you can control it via a call to `pthread_attr_setstacksize()` (assuming you are using pthreads).

As for the interrupt using the userland stack, I somewhat doubt it, as accessing userland memory is a kind of a hassle from the kernel, especially from an interrupt routine. But I don't know for sure.