# Linux kernel/userland resizing the stack? Why only 135k initially?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, x86, stack, x86-64

I notice that when I run a minimal native Linux x86-64 application it has a stack setup for it by the kernel.  When I look in `/proc/<pid>/maps` I see:

```
7ffffffde000-7ffffffff000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0   [stack]
```

And when I inspect the RSP register it holds `0x7fffffffe0c0`.

What I don't understand is why the stack is only 135k bytes.  I would have expected the stack mmap to be in the order of megabytes on x86-64.  Or does the stack mmap have some magical properties that I am not aware of?

Is it the userland applications responsibility to manually resize the stack somehow at run-time to avoid a stack overflow?  If so, by what mechanism?  Or does the kernel do this automatically?

Comment: Does this help:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270945/linux-stack-sizes ?

Comment: I guess that what you need is `ulimit -s`

Comment: @RahulTripathi: I think that is talking about stacks in kernel threads.  This asks about the userland stack.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/63742/what-is-automatic-stack-expansion has some interesting info too

Comment: Yes, "automatic stack expansion" is what I want to know about.